# column type and if statement

Tags: php, mysql, int, double

guys! 
i want to make this statement:
cost 1-3 -> maximum in inventory = 10 
cost 4-6 -> maximum in inventory = 5 
cost 7-9 -> maximum in inventory = 3 
cost over 10 -> maximum in inventory = 1

when i get product cost from DB, for example 6.00, it works, but, if i get product cost from DB for example 6.50, it doesn't work, i've tried these types for column : DOUBLE,FLOAT,INT
all of them didn't work with me :'( 
this is my code

```
     if($fetch->product_cost >=1 AND $fetch->product_cost <= 3){
        print "
        <td width='10px'>10</td>
        ";
        }elseif($fetch->product_cost >=4 AND $fetch->product_cost <= 6){
        print "
        <td width='10px'>5</td>
        ";
        }elseif($fetch->product_cost >=7 AND $fetch->product_cost <= 9){
        print "
        <td width='10px'>3</td>
        ";
        }elseif($fetch->product_cost <=10){
        print "
        <td width='10px'>1</td>
        ";
        }
```

Comment: What about in between costs like 3-4, 6-7, 9-10 ? Just because you don't have them, the 6.5 did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PHP and don't expect a native MySQL solution the easiest way is to run 3 separate MySQL queries, employing the BETWEEN capability. For example

Select * from your table where product_cost between 4 and 6